# Is the chest in Maz Kanata’s basement the same chest as the one in Obi-Wan Kenobi’s hut?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens* we see Rey seemingly beckoned by magical voices that only she can hear emanating from something Maz Kanata’s castle basement on Takodana. Rey runs around looking for the source of the voices she’s mysteriously hearing, opens up a wooden storage chest and find’s Luke/Anakin Skywalker’s lightsaber which was lost in Luke’s duel with Darth Vader at Cloud City in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

Okay, with that established is it at all possible that the wooden storage chest Rey discovers and opens to find the lightsaber in Maz Kanata’s basement is actually Ben (Obi Wan) Kenobi’s wooden storage chest from his <strike>[pied-à-terre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-%C3%A0-terre)/bachelor pad</strike> hut on Tatooine? I mean Ben just ditched that place without giving anyone any notice. It’s conceivable his belongings ended up on space-eBay, right?

Screenshots of what I just described below:

[image: Ben Kenobi opening up his magic chest.]

[image: He could have flipped that on Space-eBay but decided to respect his friend’s wishes.]

Given how small-scale the relationships in the *Star Wars* universe are—everyone seems to know each other or are related to each other—and all of the other happy coincidences we see in this film, it makes you think!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### No.

As you can see in this image, [the chest in Obi-Wan's hut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWJ8F.jpg) is pretty big, and comes to above the knee. While [officially](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi) Obi-Wan Kenobi is six feet tall (1.82 meters), the actor who played him, Alec Guinness, was only 5'10" (Ewan McGregor is also 5'10", interestingly). Referencing that, and R2-D2's height of 3 foot 7 inches, the chest in Obi-Wan's hut appears to be almost three feet tall:

[image]

It's also slightly curved, and has a lid that is several inches tall:

[image]

Whereas the chest that Rey discovered is small enough to sit on a stone table, and has no stitching on the sides of the lid, which appears to be only about an inch thick:

[image]

It seems to be just big enough to hold the lightsaber with some extra space on either side. Knowing that Maz Kanata is only [four feet (1.24 meters) tall](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata), the chest would have to be nearly 3/4ths as tall as her in order to be near the same dimensions as Obi-Wan's chest. As we can see, however, it's not even as tall as her torso, which looks to be approximately 1/4th of her total height.

[image]

Comment: @RedCaio You should add that image to your own answer; it doesn't fit thematically with mine. Also it might be a good idea to use the [published source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/star-wars-the-force-awakens/maz-kanata-facts-theories-questions/) of the image rather than just a direct link. Though it might interest you to know there are [much higher resolution images](http://imgur.com/a/7PLzS) available.

Comment: @TylerH This response has to be the last thing I would have expected. Most users are glad to have a better image. Suit yourself I guess. :) Thanks for the high-res link though.

Comment: @RedCaio In my opinion the image didn't add anything to *this* answer, because this answer is a comparison of the two chests using nearby characters for size references. If it were an answer that simply described what Maz' chest looked like, then it would've been possibly *the* best image to have.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I'd like this to be Obi Wan's chest as well, if you read the Marvel Star Wars comics, which are now canon, Boba Fett actually rendezvous with Luke to Obi Wan's place and pretty much blows up everything in it, leaving very little left.

Comment: @andriluvsfood - which comic does that occur in?

Comment: He and Luke [sure make a mess of the place](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qHU3g.png), but I don't see the chest being destroyed, plus there's plenty of Ben's crap that seems to survive intact.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell - [Marvel Star Wars #006](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/52657/star_wars_2015_6)

Comment: @Richard thanks - I've picked up the trade paperback collection of Vader and Shattered Empire but not the others.

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious sign is the hasp on the front of Maz' trunk. Obi-Wan does not have to do anything to open the chest except to lift the lid. I was hoping that it would be the same chest, but it is clearly not.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. While this answer may be correct, it does not add anything to the already accepted answer. Please visit the tour page to see what kind of answers we are looking for.